# How to change value for a particular key on button click in app.config

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

i want to update a url which i am getting from user.After validate this i want to change value for  NavigateURL

```
<setting name="NavigateURL" serializeAs="String">
    <value></value>
</setting>
```

How to change dynamically.

Comment: What is the idea behind this, if I may ask?

Comment: I am just doing an authentication part to switch user towards another application.If i do not get key value than i must update it once user enter in text box

Answer (score 0):

Try this on button click event handler:

```
Settings.Default.NavigateURL= "my new url";
```

Another approach which saves the config change too.

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("/");
string oldValue = config.AppSettings.Settings["NavigateURL"].Value;
config.AppSettings.Settings["NavigateURL"].Value = "NewValue";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Comment: App is what exactly ?

Comment: @user1280492 Settings file.

Comment: @user1280492 try with ConfigurationManager instead.

Comment: I dont think ConfigurationManager has OpenWebConfiguration such method